# Trigger blur on focused element, on click outside of iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, onblur

I have a page with an iframe in it. Inside the iframe is a contenteditable section, which saves on the onblur event. This works fine as long as the onblur event happens inside the iframe (clicking in another area inside of the same iframe).

However if the user clicks outside the iframe area (parent), then the blur event never gets triggered inside the iframe (child), and so the data does not save.

How can I get the onblur event to trigger in the iframe, even with a click outside of the iframe in the parent?

All of the answers I can find on this involve the opposite scenario, with the click inside the iframe to trigger event in the parent. How do I do the opposite?

Comment: Can you replicate issue? Because clicking on parent page should fire any blur event inside iframe if specific element inside it was focused. BTW, on each browser are you testing it? Is it cross domain iframe?

Comment: @A.Wolff Ok, then it may be specific to my case. My app is loaded inside another systems window (in an iframe itself), so my app is loaded inside an iframe in which I have an iframe of my own.. both are on same domain. I will check to see if the parent frame I am inside (outside of my control) is cancelling the default blur event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the issue was the blur event not being passed along to my editor. Adding the below code inside the iFrame with the editor in it, makes it work as expected:

```
$("[contenteditable='true']").blur(function(e) {
  editor1.trigger('blur', e, $(e.target));
})
```